# Students in a class receive their grades as Pass/Fail

Tags: python-3.x, function

Students in a class receive their grades as Pass/Fail. Scores of 60 or more (out of 100) mean that the grade is "Pass". For lower scores, the grade is "Fail". In addition, scores above 95 (not included) are graded as "Top Score".

```
def exam_grade(score):
    if 100 > 95:
        grade = "Top Score"
    elif  95 >55:
        grade = "Pass"
    else:
        grade = "Fail"
    return grade

print(exam_grade(65)) # Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(55)) # Should be Fail
print(exam_grade(60)) # Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(95)) # Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(100)) # Should be Top Score
print(exam_grade(0)) # Should be Fail
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but notice how you never use `score`.

Comment: Did you mean to do `100 > score > 95` and `95 > score > 55`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def exam_grade(score):
    if score==100:
    grade = "Top Score"
elif score<100 and score>=60:
    grade = "Pass"
else:
    grade = "Fail"
return grade
print(exam_grade(65)) #Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(55)) #Should be Fail
print(exam_grade(60)) #Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(95)) #Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(100)) #Should be Top Score
print(exam_grade(0)) #Should be Fail
```

> ```
> [Here is the screenshot of the output-1]: [Output][1]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
def exam_grade(score):
    if score > 95:
        grade = "Top Score"
    elif  60<=score<95:
        grade = "Pass"
    else:
        grade = "Fail"
    return grade
```

Please Correct your code...

Answer (score 0):

```
def exam_grade(score):
if score>95:
    grade = "Top Score"
elif score>=60:
    grade = "Pass"
else:
    grade = "Fail"
return grade
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:-

***Note:***- Hey Guys Here We have Max grades Score is 100  in this Question

**Explanation :-**

1. In addition, scores above 95 (not included) are graded as "Top Score".
   *We can Write this :-*

> `if score > 95: #95 is not included`

2. Scores of 60 or more (out of 100) mean that the grade is "Pass".
   *We can Write this :-*

> `elif score>=60 :`

3. Scores of less than 60 (out of 100) mean that the grade is "fail".
   *We can Write this :-*

> `else :   #score<60`

**Accurate Answer :-**

```
def exam_grade(score):
     if  score > 95:
        grade = "Top Score"
     elif  score>=60:  
         grade = "Pass"
     else:
        grade = "Fail"
     return grade

print(exam_grade(65)) # Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(55)) # Should be Fail
print(exam_grade(60)) # Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(95)) # Should be Pass
print(exam_grade(100)) # Should be Top Score
print(exam_grade(0)) # Should be Fail
print(exam_grade(98)) # Should be Top score
```

**Output :-**

```
Pass
Fail
Pass
Pass
Top Score
Fail
Top Score
```